my window is 11 but i got error "Windows 7 or newer is required to run the Android Emulator." exit code 1. android studio || dart || Emulator
My window is 11 pro i update this yesterday but still got the same issue on android studio update the OS please suggest some idea to solve this an run the emulator.
This is idea.log
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 31 - Windows 7 or newer is required to run the Android Emulator.
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 31 - Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4  Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377
2024-10-25 15:51:20,115 [ 482717] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 31 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-10-25 15:51:20,117 [ 482719] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 31 - OS: Windows 11
 INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 31 - Please upgrade your operating system.
SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 31 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1



May be your Android Studio version is too old for your new Windows version 11 24H2.

My Android Studio version is:- Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
I checked everything don't know why I got this issue..
even in vs code I got this error:- The Android emulator exited with code -1073741515 during startup
Android emulator stderr:
Address these issues and try again.
if you have any suggestions so please ping me here.


enable hyper-v
restart the system
installing vc redist x64

